X11 Xlib: ungrab/disable button press of external window
I'm creating a window manager for kiosks (and alike) using Xlib. There's one scenario where I'd like to disable all button presses to a specific window (to disable any touch input like a video-player pause). I tried XUngrabButton, but the documentation states:
The XUngrabButton function releases the passive button/key combination on the specified window if it was grabbed by this client.
Is it possible to void all button events from a specific window?
